# PHRoute class not found when routing

Tags: php, routes

I started with [PHRoute](https://github.com/mrjgreen/phroute) today and I have problem with loading classes.

I have following directory structure:

```
/
   public
      index.php
   app
      controllers
         Home.php
      models
      views
```

I want make routes in index.php

```
use Phroute\Phroute\RouteCollector;
use Phroute\Phroute\Dispatcher;

// Autoloader for Composer
if (file_exists(ROOT . 'vendor/autoload.php')) {
    require ROOT . 'vendor/autoload.php';
}
// load application config (error reporting etc.)
require APP . 'config/config.php';

function _autoload($class)
{
    $path = APP . "controllers/" . $class . ".php";
    if(file_exists(stream_resolve_include_path($path)))
        require($path);
}

spl_autoload_register("_autoload");

$router = new RouteCollector();

$router->any('/', ['Home','displayUser']);

$dispatcher = new Dispatcher($router->getData());

try {
    $response = $dispatcher->dispatch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

echo $response;
```

Home.php looks like:

```
class Home {   
   public function displayUser()
   {
    return 'This is the default page and will respond to /controller and /controller/index';
   }    
}
```

**I am still getting error "Uncaught Error: Class 'Home' not found...". Where I made mistake?**

Comment: Have you echoed the $path that _autoload($class) works with - and whether the condition is true (i.e. path / file exists)? See if it gives you any hints as to why the routing doesn't work.

Comment: It not work even without exist checking

Comment: You should use the file_exists check; I suggested you take a look at what $path actually is, so you can see if it makes sense.

Comment: It makes sense. Everything work ok and class auto-include when i call it manually, but when its called from PHRouter it not work

Comment: Nobody knows? Nobody ever worked with this ?